# mysql select grouping by and datdiff on the rows

Tags: mysql, datediff

Given this data:

```
workercode | timestamp          | action |
01         | 19/07/20 09:00:00  | _in     |
01         | 19/07/20 16:00:00  | _out    |
01         | 20/07/20 09:00:00  | _in     |
01         | 20/07/20 13:00:00  | _out    |
02         | 16/07/20 09:00:00  | _in     | 
02         | 16/07/20 15:00:00  | _out    |
```

I need to get for each user, how many hours did he stay in on that day. Something like:

```
01 | 19/07/20 | 7 |
01 | 20/07/20 | 4 |
02 | 16/07/20 | 6 |
```

I'm trying grouping by `workercode` and `cast(timestamp, date)` and trying something like datediff on the select but I can't get quite there.
Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.  What happens if the ins and outs don't match?  What if the time period for a given in spans multiple days?

Comment: Don't take that on account. In this particular case is not possible that there is not an out for each in and the period will be max within the same day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

It's for MsSql.

```
// For MS SQL.    
    CREATE TABLE TEST(workercode int, timestamp DATETIME2, action NVARCHAR(10))
    
    INSERT INTO dbo.TEST(workercode, timestamp, action) VALUES (1, '19/07/20 09:00:00', '_in')
    INSERT INTO dbo.TEST(workercode, timestamp, action) VALUES (1, '19/07/20 16:00:00', '_out')
    INSERT INTO dbo.TEST(workercode, timestamp, action) VALUES (1, '20/07/20 09:00:00', '_in')
    INSERT INTO dbo.TEST(workercode, timestamp, action) VALUES (1, '20/07/20 13:00:00', '_out')
    INSERT INTO dbo.TEST(workercode, timestamp, action) VALUES (2, '16/07/20 09:00:00', '_in')
    INSERT INTO dbo.TEST(workercode, timestamp, action) VALUES (2, '16/07/20 15:00:00', '_out')


SELECT temp.workercode, temp.date, DATEDIFF(HOUR, MIN(temp.timestamp), MAX(temp.timestamp)) 
    FROM (SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(Year(t.timestamp), Month(t.timestamp), Day(t.timestamp)) as date, t.workercode, t.timestamp, t.action  FROM dbo.TEST as t) as temp
GROUP BY temp.date, temp.workercode
```

It's for MySql.

```
//For MySQL
CREATE TABLE TEST(workercode int, timestamp1 TIMESTAMP, action VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO TEST(workercode, timestamp1, action) VALUES (1, "19/07/20 09:00:00", "_in");
INSERT INTO TEST(workercode, timestamp1, action) VALUES (1, "19/07/20 16:00:00", "_out");
INSERT INTO TEST(workercode, timestamp1, action) VALUES (1, "20/07/20 09:00:00", "_in");
INSERT INTO TEST(workercode, timestamp1, action) VALUES (1, "20/07/20 13:00:00", "_out");
INSERT INTO TEST(workercode, timestamp1, action) VALUES (2, "16/07/20 09:00:00", "_in");
INSERT INTO TEST(workercode, timestamp1, action) VALUES (2, "16/07/20 15:00:00", "_out");


SELECT temp.workercode, temp.date, TIMEDIFF(MAX(temp.timestamp1), MIN(temp.timestamp1)) 
    FROM (SELECT DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',Year(t.timestamp1), Month(t.timestamp1), Day(t.timestamp1))) as date, t.workercode, t.timestamp1, t.action  FROM TEST as t) as temp
GROUP BY temp.date, temp.workercode;
```

But this code haven't data check.